# Resetting the last seen epoch of partition Error in Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

In Kafka producer, I am getting the following log over and over after a certain interval.

```
[Producer clientId=****] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition abc-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to 5unLP2sNT2Sf******
```

I am using the following code for the Kafka Producer

```
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
    ....
    
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, message), callback);
```

The callback function is also pretty simple

```
  

 public void onCompletion(final RecordMetadata metadata, final Exception exception) {

        if(exception == null) {
            log.debug("successfully written to kafka");
            
        } else {
            log.debug("failure while writing to kafka");
            
        }
      
    }
```

We are using KafkaClient- 3.1.2
Server: Strimzi Kafka

The Kafka Producer config looks like

```
acks = 1
batch.size = 16384
bootstrap.servers = [strimzi-kafka-bootstrap.kafka:9092]
buffer.memory = 33554432
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = ESProducer
compression.type = none
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
delivery.timeout.ms = 2147483647
enable.idempotence = false
interceptor.classes = []
key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
linger.ms = 0
max.block.ms = 9223372036854775807
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
max.request.size = 1048576
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 2147483647
retries = 3
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
transactional.id = null
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

It is pretty unclear to me what is wrong with the implementation. I followed the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652231/apache-kafka-resetting-the-last-seen-epoch-of-partition-why) but failed to understand what could be the fix for the problem.

Comment: Can you specify the Kafka-client version and which Kafka server are you using?